# Why do the following methods of the Throwable class need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, exception, throwable

```
private StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = UNASSIGNED_STACK;
private transient Object backtrace;

private synchronized StackTraceElement[] getOurStackTrace() {
    // Initialize stack trace field with information from
    // backtrace if this is the first call to this method
    if (stackTrace == UNASSIGNED_STACK ||
        (stackTrace == null && backtrace != null) /* Out of protocol state */) {
        int depth = getStackTraceDepth();
        stackTrace = new StackTraceElement[depth];
        for (int i=0; i < depth; i++)
            stackTrace[i] = getStackTraceElement(i);
    } else if (stackTrace == null) {
        return UNASSIGNED_STACK;
    }
    return stackTrace;
}

public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
    if (stackTrace != null ||
        backtrace != null /* Out of protocol state */ ) {
        fillInStackTrace(0);
        stackTrace = UNASSIGNED_STACK;
    }
    return this;
}

public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
    if (stackTrace != null ||
        backtrace != null /* Out of protocol state */ ) {
        fillInStackTrace(0);
        stackTrace = UNASSIGNED_STACK;
    }
    return this;
}
```

The above code is the jdk source code

jdk version:1.8.0_144

Shouldn't the exception stack be private to the thread? Why do you need synchronization control?

Comment: If you are asking for help debugging, you should post your log.

Comment: No, it's just a question when reading the code @KaiserKatze

Answer (score 1):

> Why do the following methods of the `Throwable` class need to be synchronized?

For the normal reasons.  There could be situations where two threads simultaneously do something that trigger either of these calls.  If they are not `synchronized` then that could  result in a race condition or a memory anomaly.

(Notice that neither `stacktrace` or `backtrace` are `volatile` so if the code tested and/or assigned them from multiple threads, there is a risk of some threads seeing stale values.)

Now a deep analysis of all of the possible code paths *might* reveal that this code would be thread-safe without declaring those methods `synchronized`.  But if it was me writing the code, I would probably used `synchronized` anyway because:

- it is *clearly* safe to use `synchronized` here, and
- the overheads of a (possibly unnecessary) mutex will be tiny relative to all of the other things that are going on when the stack trace for an exception is captured, and
- exceptions *should* be infrequent ... unless the program is using exceptions incorrectly.

---

It would be unacceptable if getting the stacktrace of an exception was not thread-safe.  Debugging Java would be a total "crap shoot" if stack traces were unreliable.  This is one of those cases where the code must be thread-safe even if the spec (the javadoc) is silent about it.

Comment: According to my understanding, if it is confirmed that it is thread-safe, then synchronization is obviously redundant. If it is not thread-safe that synchronization needs to be controlled, then I consider that if synchronization is removed, under what circumstances will cause problems, this is what I am now Doubts and puzzles

Comment: Well, your understanding is different to mine.  According to my understanding, unless you can **prove** that the code is thread-safe (in all situations) without `synchronized` you should **not** remove the synchronization.  Can you prove that?   Having "doubts" is OK, but we don't change code just because someone has "doubts".  "Doubts" are not proof.

Comment: (I should add that by "we", I meant responsible programmers ... generally.  I don't claim to speak for the Java development team.  I don't claim to speak for anyone other than myself ...)